# How to generate a P2WSH address

Tags: json-rpc, bech32-address, p2wsh

`getnewaddress "" bech32` generates a `P2WPKH` address (e.g. `tb1qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kxpjzsx`).

How can I generate a `P2WSH` address (e.g. `tb1qrp33g0q5c5txsp9arysrx4k6zdkfs4nce4xj0gdcccefvpysxf3q0sl5k7`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a P2WSH address, you need to have some script. The easiest one you can use is a multisig script. You can do this with the command `addmultisigaddress`. If you do something like

```
addmultisigaddress 1 '["37Ju7oTbPfe5qNAHYiAKfdTtVvCSP3TTdL"]' "" "bech32"
```

you should get a P2WSH address.

Comment: Works great! I just used `getnewaddress "" "bech32"` to get the address to use with `addmultisigaddress 1 '["<address>"]' "" "bech32"`

Comment: This question can really use an updated answer for descriptor wallets (where you can actually construct meaningful multisig P2WSH wallets).